# Any tips specifically on creating this sliders?

Tags: rigging

does anyone what this sliders actually called? I tried looking for it on the internet but im just not sure what's it called. I'm trying to learn on creating it.

screenshot ref from here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0f3izO2muQ&t=321s

[image]

Comment: is it a screenshot from a tutorial? if so, could you please link it? it may be custom objects that are targets of bone constraints, or drivers, or they have Action constraints in order to trigger actions... but it's just an hypothesis

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a panel that allows to control animations through *Action* constraints. Let's say that you have created an action of 2 bones bending (in the case of a face it can be the character smiling, etc), give a bone constraint to one of the 2 bones with a small bone as controller, set all the parameters and select the action you've created at the bottom of the constraint panel. Enable the *Copy Attribute* addon, select the other bone, shift select the one that has the constraint and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Copy Bone Constraint*:

[image]

Now when you move the controller it triggers the action:

[image]

You can create a lot of controllers (that can be objects or empties instead of bones) for a lot of actions and organize them as a control board.

Note that the new ***Pose Library*** is pretty close to this function and may be more convenient (except it saves poses, not animations).

But this is only an hypothesis, what you show can also be drivers or controllers for *Transformation* constraints, etc.

Comment: To me it also looks like classic driven values, the only "specific" of this post is the UI. But I suspect it's just a picture on a plane or image empty, and the handles widgets are either pictures too or mesh objects, wearing the drivers. Or it's all a bunch of text, empties and mesh objects, whatever, it's not what's harder to do in this system. It's quite an old school way of making rig UIs to be honest, and not the most appreciated amongst animayors, in my little experience in the animation industry.

Comment: Sure it looks like a custom made, don't you think that Pose Library is probably a better option? Of course it only control poses, not animations, but I guess for face expressions it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Usually these setups are either driving controllers on the face, or shapekeys if not both. So it's a different system than using poses. Besides, it's supposed to be keyed too.

Comment: Peraonally I prefer controllers on the face that just move what's visually there, ideally something [FACS](https://adamspring.co.uk/2020/05/25/facs-rigging-texture-blending-digital-humans/) based (even for cartoony rigs), with some custom controllers for fancy movements that aren't as simple as moving/rotation an area of the face.

Comment: Many of animators I've met don't really appreciate UI's that rely on panels and widgets on the side, because it feels too much disconnected. Animators like to feel like they are touching the face, contracting a muscle there, pushing some meat around. Not like they are programming a robot. And it's even more true when working on display graphics tablets IMHO

Comment: ok thanks for the explanations ;)